# Subscribe to a third party Javascript Plugin

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I try to subscribe to a javascript event in my own javascript plugin, but its not working properly and I dont have a clue what I am missing here.

In my init function of my javascript plugin I have the following code:

```
const SwkwebProductSetConfigurator = window.PluginManager.getPluginInstances("SwkwebProductSetConfigurator");
console.log(window.PluginManager.getPluginList());
console.log(SwkwebProductSetConfigurator.length);

if(SwkwebProductSetConfigurator.length > 0){
    SwkwebProductSetConfigurator[0].$emitter.subscribe(
       'swkwebProductSet/onSetAddToCart', this.onSetAddToCart[this]
    );
}
```

The list is showing the plugin, but console.log(SwkwebProductSetConfigurator.length); is outputting 0?!?
When I get the instance of e.g. "AccountMenu" count is one.

When I console.log in the init function of the third party plugin and mine, I see, that mine is executed first.

How can I solve this?

**Update:**
OK, so its important when each Plugin is installed! I uninstalled the other Plugin and reinstalled it. Afterwards I could subscribe to the event from the other plugin. Its no problem to uninstall/install plugins in a dev environment, but how can this be managed in a production shop? Additionally when my plugin is available in the shopware store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins are initialized on the `DOMContentLoaded` event so by then all plugins should've been registered and you should be able to subscribe to their events.

```js
// how the plugins are initialized
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => PluginManager.initializePlugins(), false);

// how you can do stuff depending on another plugin being registered
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const SwkwebProductSetConfigurator = window.PluginManager.getPluginInstances("SwkwebProductSetConfigurator");
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you as always for clearing things up. It would be really nice if this snipped is mentioned in the docs. ;)